# Integration of Paypal using Drupal - Which module do you recommend?

Tags: drupal, paypal, drupal-7

I'm building a Drupal website. It's for a coming and important event(symposium) at yhe university. Every participant of the event must paid it. The organization wants to use Paypal.
I'm new in Drupal 7. I need a secure and nice module to works with Paypal. I found two interesting modules on the Internet but I don't know what could be the best ?

1. Drupal Commerce.
2. Ubercart.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest drupal commerce. Integrating paypal will be easy. You can find the contrib module at https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal .

And moreover drupal commerce provides much more flexibility in dealing with ecommerce platform.